# What is bivariant parameter? ~ TypeScript

Tags: typescript, compiler-specific

The TypeScript's docs comes with [Compiler Options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html), where the `--strictFunctionTypes` is defined with its description. Unfortunately, can't get what is **bivariant parameter**. I tried to understand https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-function-parameters-bivariant as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A "bivariant" parameter is one that is both covariant and contravariant.

The [TypeScript 2.6 release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html) describe the `--strictFunctionTypes` compiler option well, since that's the first release that supported it.

> Under --strictFunctionTypes function type parameter positions are checked contravariantly instead of bivariantly. For some background on what variance means for function types check out [What are covariance and contravariance](https://www.stephanboyer.com/post/132/what-are-covariance-and-contravariance)?.

This article linked in that quote describes the difference between covariance and contravariance:
https://www.stephanboyer.com/post/132/what-are-covariance-and-contravariance

Comment: The last links with this 2 sentences "Suppose I need a List<Animal> and you pass me a List<Dog>. Since I think I have a List<Animal>, I might try to insert a Cat into it. Now your List<Dog> has a Cat in it! The type system should not allow this." describes it quite alright.