# Typescript generics of a type that intersects with type 'any' are automatically widened to be of type 'any'

Tags: typescript, generics

Refer to the snippet of code I have below:

```js
// I'm a function that does not care what the type of the argument passed through to me is
const function1 = (parameter: any) => parameter;

// I'm a function that REQUIRES a number to function
const function2 = (parameter: number) => parameter + 5;

// I'm a function that REQUIRES a string to function
const function3 = (parameter: string) => parameter.split(':');

// I'm some combinatorial function that takes in a list of functions, and returns a "meta function"
function functionAggregator<A1, R1, R2>(f1: (a1: A1) => R1, f2: (a1: A1) => R2): (a1: A1) => [R1, R2] {
  return (a1: A1) => [f1(a1), f2(a1)];
}

const validMetaFunction = functionAggregator(function1, function2);
// Valid because parameters of type number and any can overlap

const invalidMetaFunction = functionAggregator(function2, function3);
// Invalid because parameters of type number and string cannot overlap



const validFunctionResult = validMetaFunction(5);
// Valid result, because we passed in a number

const invalidFunctionResult = validMetaFunction('string');
// SHOULD be marked as an error, since type string cannot be passed into function2, which requires a type of number
```

On the very last line, I would *expect* `validMetaFunction('string');` to be marked as invalid code, but because `function1` has a parameter of type `any`, the metaFunction's parameter type is *widened* to be of type `any`. . .

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Don't use `any`?  Does `unknown` work for you instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Type intersections using any](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46673558/type-intersections-using-any)

Comment: @jcalz I've read that question, though what I'm asking is more related to generics: I'm *aware* that an intersection with type `any` will widen to type `any`, but I'm wondering if I can use the magic of generics to *infer* the sister function's type, and use it instead?

Not specifying a type for function1 will default to any. Specifying it as type `unknown` has the same widening issue as type `any` - metaFunction's parameter is type `unknown`, so strings can still be passed in.

Comment: Is your code a [mcve]?  When [I test it](https://tsplay.dev/vWkkDW) I see the results you seem to expect/want.  What, specifically, is going wrong?

Comment: It is a minimal reproducible example. I *want* my IDE to infer that passing in a string to `validMetaFunction` will result in an error. I *want* it to look like this: https://imgur.com/a/NqZ2Q0d. Note that in order to make it show as an error, I had to change `function1` to be of type `number` (not `any`) -- when `function1` is of type `any` (like I have in my snippet above), that last line is not underlined as an error.

Comment: oh huh. . . I just opened the example you gave, and you're right, it's showing as an error for you. Ok clearly this is a problem on my end. Maybe I'm not using the latest version of typescript. Lemme try updating that real quick~~

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz)'s [tsplay](https://tsplay.dev/vWkkDW) link, I was able to determine that the issue stems from Typescript's default function type handling, which is bivariance. If you disable `strictFunctionTypes` in the tsplay link above, then it will incorrectly check the types. But with `strictFunctionTypes` enabled, the types flow through, as they should.

[This stack overflow does a good job of explaining what that compiler option does.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57499459/what-is-bivariant-parameter-typescript)